# how to convert Array<(out) Event!> to and from ArrayList<Event> after passing data using safe args in Navigation Controller?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-navigation, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-navigation

I am trying pass ArrayList data from one fragment to another fragment using safe args, here is the argument

```
<argument
        android:name="upcomingEvents"
        app:argType="com.x.Models.Event[]" />
```

but when I want to pass data using safe args, I have this error
[image]

it is said that

> type mismatch.
>
> required: Array<(out) Event!>
>
> Found: ArrayList

how to convert `ArrayList<Event>` to `Array<(out) Event!>` ?

and also vice versa , how to convert `Array<(out) Event!>` to `ArrayList<Event>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kotlin has built in methods for both operations, namely, [`toTypedArray()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-typed-array.html) and [`asList()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-list.html):

```
val upcomingEvents = currentUserData!!.upcomingEvents
val array = upcomingEvents.toTypedArray()

// On the other side
val array = ...
val list = array.asList()
```